# Cursor behaviour in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am building a program where users can fill out prompt questions, and the answers to those questions then form a part of a template letter they can fill out. I would like their responses to be shown in red, so they can easily see if they somehow look strange or don't fit.

The current way I am approaching this is with a contentEditable div, where the substrings are rendered within span tags.

So far, so good - this is working fine; until I try to save what they are changing in state.

Then there is an issue where any time the user inputs anything, the cursor jumps backwards several spaces.

I have made a version of it that you can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-gianmarco-f553zd?file=/src/App.js

I would like for the div to function exactly as a normal textfield might, just with the substrings highlighted in red.

I understand the cursor issue - is to do with the div being re-rendered as the state changes. I've tried to play around with saving and restoring the cursor position, but I can't make that work for me.

Comment: Try using it outside of React, the same as you have controlled and not controlled form components. To fix this set newTemplate only when component is mounted.